# XML files to dataframe - Brazilian Senate

Tags: r, xml, dataframe, opendata

Good afternoon, everyone!

I am relatively new to R and during my experience, I have had never had to deal with XML files. However, I am currently on a project in which I need to open the **nominal votes for the Brazilian Senate** (you can find the data here: https://www12.senado.leg.br/dados-abertos/legislativo/plenario/votacoes-nominais) from 1991 to 2019 and all the files are XML.

I have already done the same process for the Brazilian Congress but files were csv. The data frame that I am trying to get needs to has the following parameters:

CodigoSessao; SiglaCasa; CodigoSessaoLegislativa; TipoSessao; NumeroSessao; DataSessao;
HoraInicio; CodigoSessaoVotacao; SequencialSessao; Secreta; DescricaoVotacao; Resultado; VotoParlamentar; CodigoParlamentar; NomeParlamentar; SexoParlamentar; SiglaPartido; SiglaUF; Voto;

I would really apreciate any guidance on how to deal with these data. Also, if you have any problems with all the Portuguese, please send me a message here or even an e-mail (gbrogim@hotmail.com). I will respond as soon as possible and help you with the translation (I want to help you help me :)

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Here looks like a good process overview [Deus Mio, XML!](https://urbandatapalette.com/post/2021-03-xml-dataframe-r/).

Comment: Thanks, Chris!! It will definitely help.